# Where would I intoduce a default constructor in working c++ code and why?

Tags: c++, constructor, default

everyone. I am a total neophyte to c++. 
  Here is some code that is working. I now need to introduce a default contructor. 
  Which of the two methods should I do that for - the one inside the class or the one outside the class?  Why would I do that?  And then how exactly would I call it from Main?

Thanks!

THIS HAS BEEN EDITED SINCE THE ORIGINAL POST.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date {
    private:
        int a;
        int b;
        int comparison;
        int result;
        int userdate;
        int usermonth;
        int remainder;
        int userday;
        int useryear;
    public:
        Date (int a);
        Date();
        /* Date(); */
};
Date::Date(){
        comparison = a - b;
        if (comparison == 0){result = 0;}
        else {result = 1;}
        if (result = 1)
        {cout<<"The years are different. ";}
        else{
        cout<<"The years are the same. ";}
            }
Date::Date(int userdate){
        a = userdate;
        usermonth = a/1000000;
        remainder = a%1000000;
        userday = remainder/10000;
        useryear = remainder%10000;
        cout << "The date you entered is: " << usermonth <<" " << userday << " "<< useryear<<"\n";
        cout<<"Please enter a second date: ";
        cin >>b;
        usermonth = b/1000000;
        remainder = b%1000000;
        userday = remainder/10000;
        useryear = remainder%10000;
        cout << "The date you entered is: " << usermonth <<" " << userday << " "<< useryear<<"\n";
}
int main()
{
    int first;
    cout<<"Please enter a date in the format MMDDYYY: ";
    cin >>first;
    Date firstdate(first);
    Date();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to "introduce" a default constructor.

Comment: I think you need to read some basic [Class Tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Comment: This is pretty messy, definitely read up on c++ more

Comment: Use the `<c…>` versions of headers instead of `<….h>`. The latter are deprecated in C++. Of course, at first glance, I see you're missing `#include <string>` and I don't see any code that uses the two C headers.

Answer (score 3):

> I now need to introduce a default contructor.

No, you don't.

You only need to write your own constructors if your members don't already have the correct initialisation behaviour.

In the case of your `Date` class, its only member is a `std::string`, and a `std::string` knows how to default-construct itself in a sensible way (by creating an empty string).

---

P.S.: If you already added some other self-written constructor, e.g. a copy constructor, to your class, then you need to provide your own default constructor if you still need default construction of instances of your class:

```
class Date {
//...
    Date(Date const &); // copy constructor
};

Date d; // will no longer work if you do not also provide a default constructor
```

Comment: You also may need to provide a default constructor if you have provided other constructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, that's why I said "your own constructors". I meant it in the general sense, for all kinds of constructors. But I shall add a clarifying line about that anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the two methods should I do that for - the one inside the class or the one outside the class?

Both will work. If your constructor is short you may define it within the class.

> And then how exactly would I call it from Main?

You already are calling it in `main` in the line where you declared `first year` variable.

Comment: OK here is the cleaned up version - seems to be working. Could be less lines of code if I put a loop in the second consttructor ...

Comment: Dang it - where can I post the code?

Comment: why you want to post it if it's working? :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class you need to specify at least the constructor's signature, which looks like:
Date()
in most cases, it should be public

you can now decide to specify the implementation inside (like the get_date method) and it would look something like:

```
Date() {
  // the constructor implementation 
  // (usually it initializes the private members with default values)
}
```

or you can specify it outside (like the same_year method) and it would look something like:

```
Date::Date() {
  // the constructor implementation 
  // (usually it initializes the private members with default values)
}
```

It is really your choice.

Regarding the call, you do not need to do anything. It is a default constructor, so it is called by default.

The statement: Date firstyear; actually calls this default constructor. Until you explicitly define it, a default constructor generated by the compiler is called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wojtek's answer. Depending on whether or not you need to give parameters to the `firstYear` object. You will need to create the object and set the parameters at the same time.

To create the constructor in the date class you can do this:

```
Date(){/*Whichever code you need to do upon creating an object of Date*/}
```

This will create a default constructor where you can initialize variables within your class or do other stuff you need to have done.

To create a constructor which takes arguments you simply do this:

```
Date(/*"Type_of_Variable varName" for as many variable you want to send it and use*/){/*Whichever code you need to do upon creating an object of Date*/}
```

To create an object of the Data class with the parameters, in your main class, do this:

```
Date firstYear(/*variables go in here*/);
```

Comment: Thank you, Darrell, and thank you everyone!! Yep, it is definitely messy and nope I really don't need to add constructors in this case. It is an exercise I am doing for a course to learn c++. The course is totally FREE (thru Saylor.org) but as a result there are limited resources when you are stumped (hey, you get what you pay for). So thank you again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to introduce a default constructor if you have default values that you want to assign to the variables in your class. A default constructor also implies that it doesn't need any arguments.

To declare the constructor in your class, you will declare it like any other function, except there won't be a return type (because constructors don't have return types). Also, make sure that it is public, as this is what the user will use to declare an object. This is what it should look like:

```
Date();
```

Now, you need to actually write what the constructor will do, outside of the class, like you would do for any other function. Once again, you can leave out the return type, since there is no return type:

```
Date::Date() {  }
```

Inside the curly brackets, you can initialize the values of your class.

My two favorite ways for calling the constructor from main are as follows:

```
Date* date = new Date();
```

This first method is creating a pointer to the object date. Or, you can do it this way:

```
Date date;
```

This is simply declaring the object.

Keep in mind that with both of these methods for calling the constructor, actually declaring the constructor is optional.

Here is one of my favorite articles explaining constructors; you may find it helpful:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html